# HTTP-Method PHP based REST API results in 404 Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, rest

That's the website structure.:
[image: Thats the website structure.]

I want to enter ..../posts without any extension like .php for getting a JSON response. But what's going wrong.

index.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

include_once('./core/initialize.php');

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri = explode('/', $uri);




if($uri[1] !== 'posts'){
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  exit();
}

$id = null;
if(isset($uri[2])){
  $id = (int) $uri[2];
}




$requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$controller = new PostController($dbconn, $requestMethod, $id);
$controller->processRequest();

 ?>
```

initialize.php

```
<?php

  defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'xxx');
  defined('INC_PATH') ? null : define('INC_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');
  defined('CORE_PATH') ? null : define('CORE_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'core');

  require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'dbconn.php');



  defined('GATEWAY_PATH') ? null : define('GATEWAY_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'gateway');
  defined('CONTROLLER_PATH') ? null : define('CONTROLLER_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'controller');

  require_once(GATEWAY_PATH.DS.'PostGateway.php');
  require_once(CONTROLLER_PATH.DS.'PostController.php');
  
 ?>
```

dbconn.php

```
<?php
  $db_host = 'uuu';
  $db_user = 'xxx';
  $db_password = 'yyy';
  $db_name = 'zzz';

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);

  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  define('APP_NAME', 'xxx');

 ?>
```

PostGateway.php

```
<?php

class PostGateway{

  private $conn;
  private $table = 'posts';

  public $id;
  public $category_id;
  public $category_name;
  public $title;
  public $body;
  public $author;
  public $create_at;

  public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;

  }

  public function findall(){
    $query = 'SELECT
      c.name as category_name,
      p.id,
      p.category_id,
      p.title,
      p.body,
      p.author,
      p.create_at
      FROM
      ' .$this->table . ' p
      LEFT JOIN
        categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
        ORDER BY p.create_at DESC';

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();

      return $stmt;
  }


  public function find($id){
    $query = 'SELECT
      c.name as category_name,
      p.id,
      p.category_id,
      p.title,
      p.body,
      p.author,
      p.create_at
      FROM
      ' .$this->table . ' p
      LEFT JOIN
        categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
        WHERE p.id = ? LIMIT 1';

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
      $stmt->execute();

      $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $this->title = $row['title'];
      $this->body = $row['body'];
      $this->author = $row['author'];
      $this->category_id = $row['category_id'];
      $this->category_name = $row['category_name'];

      return $stmt;
  }

  public function insert(Array $input){
    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' + $this->table + '
      (category_id, title, body, author, create_at) VALUES
      (:category_id, :title, :body, :author, :create_at);';

    $stmt = $this->conn->preprare($query);
    $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['category_id']));
    $this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['title']));
    $this->body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['body']));
    $this->author = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['author']));
    $this->create_at = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['create_at']));

    $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
    $stmt->bindParam(':create_at', $this->create_at);

    if($stmt->execute()){
      return true;
    }

    printf("Error $s. \n", $stmt->error);
    return false;
  }

  public function update($id, Array $input){
    $query = 'UPDATE ' + $this->table + '
    SET
      category_id = :category_id,
      title = :title,
      body = :body,
      author = :author,
      create_at = :create_at
    WHERE id = :id;
    ';

    $stmt = $this->conn->preprare($query);

    $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($id));
    $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['category_id']));
    $this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['title']));
    $this->body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['body']));
    $this->author = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['author']));
    $this->create_at = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input['create_at']));

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
    $stmt->bindParam(':create_at', $this->create_at);

    if($stmt->execute()){
      return true;
    }

    printf("Error $s. \n", $stmt->error);
    return false;
  }

  public function delete($id){
    $query = 'DELETE FROM ' + $this->table + '
    WHERE id = :id;
    ';

    $stmt = $this->conn->preprare($query);

    $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($id));
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

    if($stmt->execute()){
      return true;
    }

    printf("Error $s. \n", $stmt->error);
    return false;
  }

}

 ?>
```

With this code above I got the following result in Postman
Error result:
[image: Error result]

Comment: I don't see nginx/apache rewrite rules

Comment: Ok sure, a proposal to generate a rewrite rule in .htaccess or php file?

Comment: Since `/posts` does not exist (according to the structure you provided) then presumably requesting `/posts` will generate a 404 error. You can either use an `.htaccess` RewriteRule to point requests for `/post` to `index.php` or you can use a RewriteRule to tell the server that 404 requests get handled by `index.php` (e.g. `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`).

Comment: Thanks for this, now I understand the purpose. After solving this problem, I got an additional error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PostController' not found in .../api..../index.php: 34

Seems like an simple issue and meaningful feedback but I really don't know where the worm is in :(
Line 34: $controller = new PostController($dbconn, $requestMethod, $id);